# How is the mass flow between 2 streamlines derived?

Tags: aerodynamics

I am reading "Fundamental of Aerodynamics " by J.D.Anderson Fifth edition, At pages 177 and 178 (section 2.14 Stream funciton), the book said: given 2D steady flow, from:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{v}{u}$$
with u and v are known function of x and y, then we obtain f(x,y) = c by intergration.

If we have steamline 1 is f(x,y) = c1 and streamline 2 is f(x,y) = c2, then why is the mass flow between two streamlines equal (c2 - c1)? The book said that but there is no derivation of that.

As far as I can do:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: **Because that's how we've defined $c_1$ and $c_2$.**

Long answer: Read 2.14 carefully. As you've said, we have $f(x,y)=c$ via integration. Anderson then chooses $\bar{\psi}$ as $f$ (a convention) to get $\bar{\psi}=c_1$ and $\bar{\psi}=c_2$ for the two streamlines. However, we know that $c_1$ and $c_2$ are just arbitrary constants of integration that we can set to whatever we want. Anderson just happens to know that later down the road it will be helpful to

> define the numerical value of $\bar{\psi}$ such that the *difference* $\Delta\bar{\psi}$ [between the two streamlines] is equal to the *mass* flow between the two streamlines.

Furthermore,

> $\Delta\bar{\psi}$ equaling mass flow (per unit depth) between streamlines is natural. For a steady flow, the mass flow inside a given streamtube is constant along the tube; the mass flow across any cross section of the tube is the same. Since $\Delta\bar{\psi}$ is equal to this mass flow, then $\Delta\bar{\psi}$ itself is constant for a given streamtube.

Comment: OMG, I just found out that it's just defined ;)) I also just know that: with that definition, we can obtain the velocity field from such stream fuctions. Thanks